# como puedo crear variables desde un bucle for php

Tags: php

tengo 3 datos
cod-es, cod-a y contador
lo que quiero es que segun el contador se genere n variables 
Ejemplo

```
$campo1 = $_POST['dato'];
$campo2 = $_POST['dato2'];
```

Comment: Que llevas hasta ahorita?

Comment: N variables me suena a un Array

Answer (score 1):

En PHP puedes nombrar tus variables dinámicamente:

```
$nombre = 'campo1';
$$nombre = 'valor1';
echo $campo1;
```

imprimirá 'valor1'

Lo que acabas de hacer cuando declaras `$$nombre` es declarar `$campo1`.

Si tienes un contador que te dice cuántos campos recibirás por $_POST, puedes iterar sobre ellos. Digamos que $_POST es un array que contiene

```
[
 'contador'=>4,
 'dato1'=>'pedro',
 'dato2'=>'juan',
 'dato3'=>'diego',
 'dato4'=>'alejandro'
]
```

Puedes hacer:

```
<?php
$SEUDO_POST=    [
     'contador'=>4,
     'dato1'=>'pedro',
     'dato2'=>'juan',
     'dato3'=>'diego',
     'dato4'=>'alejandro'
    ];

for($i=1;$i<=$SEUDO_POST['contador'];$i++) {
    $nombre ='dato'.$i;

    $$nombre = $SEUDO_POST[$nombre];
}

print_r([$dato1,$dato2,$dato3,$dato4]);
```

Puedes verlo funcionando [en un fiddle](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/d76ef84a1bfdbd89caab58a4aea4828040f0edf5).

Ahora... esta no es la única manera de hacerlo. También podrías usar [extract $SEUDO_POST](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/157a3b0cf4254f1b95a895877e0ace0589488448)

Pero es mala idea usar extract. El día de mañana llega alguien a mantener tu código y sin tener idea qué contiene `$_POST` se puede encontrar con:

```
extract($_POST);
echo $dato1;
```

Y no tendrá la menor idea de dónde salió `$dato1`. Peor todavía, alguien puede enviar una variable por POST manipulando tu formulario, y sobreescribir una variable que ya tengas declarada, logrando manejar tu backend indirectamente.

En todo caso, **lo que sea que necesites hacer con $campo1 y $campo2, lo puedes hacer con un simple array asociativo**, usando `$miarray['campo1']` en vez de `$campo1`.

Answer (score 0):

Dado que pusiste el ejemplo de un `$_POST`, te pondré un ejemplo de lo que quieres hacer usando `extract`. El Manual advierte de no usar esta función con valores que no son de confianza, a no ser que le pongas la bandera `EXTR_SKIP`, esto es para prevenir el riesgo de manipulación de código.  En ese sentido, el uso de `eval` es muchísimo más peligroso.

Lo que hace `extract` es:

> Importar variables a la tabla de símbolos actual desde un array
>
> <sub>[`extract` en el Manual de PHP](https://www.php.net/manual/es/function.extract.php)</sub>

Dado que `$_POST` es un array, lo puedes hacer perfectamente con él, como también con un array cualquiera.

Veamos:

```
$count=3;
for ($i = 1; $i <= $count; $i++) {
    $k="llave$i";
    $v="valor$i";
    $_POST[$k]=$v;
}
extract($_POST, EXTR_SKIP);

echo $llave1.PHP_EOL;
echo $llave2.PHP_EOL;
echo $llave3.PHP_EOL;
```

***Salida:***

```
valor1
valor2
valor3
```

Si imprimes `print_r($_POST)` podrás ver esto:

```
Array
(
    [llave1] => valor1
    [llave2] => valor2
    [llave3] => valor3
)
```

Y si lo recorres en un bucle:

```
foreach ($_POST as $llave){
    echo $llave.PHP_EOL;
}
```

***Salida:***

```
valor1
valor2
valor3
```

---

### Demostraciones del código

Puedes ver una <kbd>**[DEMO DEL CÓDIGO](http://rextester.com/RAWS55448)**</kbd> usado en la respuesta, ver una prueba usando un array normal y hacer otras pruebas.

Espero sea de utilidad.

Comment: No tenía idea del flag `EXTR_SKIP`, aunque sigo pensando que dificulta la lectura del código para otros mantenedores. Y evidentemente, eval es dispararse en un pie

Answer (score 0):

Dentro de tu bucle con el ejemplo que colocas. Deberías tener un "tope".
Puedes utilizarlas dentro del bucle o una vez realizada la iteración

```
$TOPE = 5; // Por ejemplo
for ($i = 0; $i <= $TOPE; $i++) {
   // Cuando sea 0, buscará dato, caso contrario seria dato1, dato2... hasta el tope
   $search = "dato" . ($i == 0 ? '' : $i);
   if (!isset($_POST[$search])){
      break; // En caso de que no exista finalice el bucle
      // O puedes continuar si hay un salto (depende de tu logica)
      // continue;
   }
   $$search = $_POST[$search]; //Acá se crean las variables.
   print_r ($$search);  // print_r de las variables dentro del bucle
}
// print_r de las variables fuera del bucle
print_r ($dato);
print_r ($dato1);
print_r ($dato2);
print_r ($dato3);
print_r ($dato4);
print_r ($dato5);
```